# How can I edit string array fields in nested_form_for rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

First Row in fields_for with "0" index :

```html
<tr class="ui-state-disabled" id="bold_col">    
    <td class="col-sm-2 drag-enable">      
        <input class="form-control diminished-font educations education col1"
               name="resume[educations_attributes][0][ecolumns][]" value="Institution"
               placeholder="Institution" type="text" id="1">
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 drag-enable">
        <input class="form-control diminished-font educations education col2"
               name="resume[educations_attributes][0][ecolumns][]" value="City"
               placeholder="City" type="text" id="2">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Second Row in fields_for with "1" index:

```html
<tr class="fields">
    <td class="col-sm-2 drag-enable">
        <%= text_field_tag 'resume[educations_attributes][1][ecolumns][]',"",:class=>"form-control diminished-font col1 educations educations",:placeholder=>"" %>
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 drag-enable" >
        <%= text_field_tag 'resume[educations_attributes][1][ecolumns][]',"",:class=>"form-control diminished-font col2 educations educations",:placeholder=>"" %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I can add any number of rows in table through "link_to_add" functionality. On creation it is working fine, but on edit, I am having issues because the name of all this fields created manually. How can I go with rails stuff here? Is there any good approach?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you talking about the `id` -- `resume[educations_attributes][x]`?

Comment: I have setup name for above fields as manually you can see,it is working during create but on edit ,what would be easy way I can go with this already created field during updation?